# object not found when I'm trying to plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm trying to get a plot from a dataset but keep getting the error "object 'country' not found" while "country" is indeed a variable in my dataset. Can someone help me figure this out?

```
> top8ghg3 %>%
 ggplot(aes(x=year,y=tonsofCO2,
            group=country)) +
 geom_line(color="grey20",size=.75) +
 facet_wrap(-country,ncol=2)
```

And the data set is shown in the attached pic. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Sorry that I couldn't attach a picture of the dataset, but "country" is the first column of the dataset.

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please post reproducible example data. `dput(head(myData))` or `head(myData)`, `str(myData)`.

Comment: Not `-country`. Try `~country` with a tilde.